# jQuery get window by name

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, jquery-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Access a window by window name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243970/access-a-window-by-window-name)

Suppose I do:

```
window.open(url, 'somewindowname');
```

How can I get a reference to the newly opened window using the window name ('somewindowname') using jQuery?

Perhaps something in the form of `$('somewindowname')` or something....

Comment: You cannot.

Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243970/access-a-window-by-window-name

Comment: @Madhur Actually, you can, check out my answer and further details in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785399/how-to-tell-if-a-window-exists-in-javascript/4785453#4785453

Answer (score 0):

you can set the window as a variable like so

```
var foo;
foo = window.open(url, 'somewindowname');
```

you can then

use

```
foo.close();
```

to close the window for instance. Note that this is a javascript variable not a jquery variable.

Comment: yea I know...I'm asking if it's possible to fetch the window by referencing the window name 'somewindowname' instead of doing this

Comment: but why? what difference would it make?

Comment: @Eonasdan In the case where some code created the window and another piece of code needs to access it

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with `JQuery`.

After opening the window for the first time, you can get a reference to it by using `window.open` function again and assigning the returned value to a variable:

```
var existingWindow = window.open(url, "somewindowname");
```

**Edit**

Here is a [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/5WeVd/) demo.

Answer (score 0):

Reference elements inside of the pop up window:

```
var imgsInPopUp = $("img", somewindowname.document.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some undocumented behavior that lets you get a reference to a window by name. I've mentioned it in this answer [How to tell if a window exists in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785399/how-to-tell-if-a-window-exists-in-javascript/4785453#4785453)

```
// Opened a window without storing a handle, but gave it a name
window.open('/some/url', 'xxx');

// Now I need to get a reference to that window
// Calling open without setting a url gets you
// a reference and doesn't reload the window
var win = window.open('', 'xxx')
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/YyK7g/)